# Django get a certin value from a dict with a for key value inside of a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Sorry if my title is a bit crypt, but this is the problem

I have a list of  dict
data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"a": 3, "b": 4} ]
and a list with keys = ["a","b"]
I want in a template do this:

```
for dat in data:

<tr>

for k in keys:

<th> dat[k]</th>

</tr>
```

to get this:

```
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of these solutions if you want to keep the order given by the `keys` list. Result will be different with `keys = ["a", "b"]` VS `keys = ["b", "a"]`.

---

## Solution 1 - Prepare data in the view

Process the data in the view. Create a list of list instead of dictionary to keep the order of your `keys` list.

```python
def home(request):
    data = [{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"a":3, "b":4}]
    data_to_render = [ [] for _i in range(len(data)) ]
    keys = ['a', 'b']
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for k in keys:
            data_to_render[i] += [data[i].get(k)]
    context = {
        "data_to_render": data_to_render
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And your template `index.html` may look like:

```html
<table>
    {% for l in data_to_render %}
        <tr>
            {% for value in l %}
                <th> {{ value }} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

## Solution 2 - Use a custom tag

Your view might look like…

```python
def home(request):
    context = {
        "data" : [{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"a":3, "b":4}],
        "keys": ["a","b"]
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Create a custom tag `getval()` at `templatetags/extras.py`:

```python
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def getval(dic, key):
    return dic.get(key)
```

Finally, your template might look like:

```html
{% load extras %}
<table>
    {% for d in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for k in keys %}
                <th> {% getval d k %} </th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. It generates your expected html. But don't use keys dic.
To use keys dic you will need to create a custom template tag for that.

```html
{% for dat in data %}
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in dat.items %}
            <th>{{ value }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zatigem , I just forgot indentation, because it works even indentation are wrong. .

Comment: Actually, this is not working because I think the OP want to keep an exact order given by the `keys` list. Try with `keys = ['b', 'a']`

Comment: Yes. But for his example, it works. Keys are unnecessary. But if he wants order by keys, should use a custom template tag.with keys.